# PyDev is installed but does not show up in ADT

Tags: python, eclipse, adt, pydev

I tried to setup PyDev on my ADT/eclipse. I am wondering the installation did not prompt any errors but I could not see pydev plugin after restarting ADT. Moreover I tried to extract plugin files in to eclipse>plugin folder for pydev it did not work either. Any solutions or ideas for it to work on ADT.

Comment: Did you try changing the perspective on the top right corner which is by default set to java

Comment: I tried that but there is no option to select PyDev, it does not show up anywhere in eclipse.

Comment: open window>open prespective>other and select pydev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-obvious answer here is that JDK 7 needs to be installed. Otherwise, the PyDev installation succeeds but then silently is hidden in Eclipse. I just went through this, and getting JDK 7 fixes it right up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Eclipse as an administartor when you do the Pydev (or any other) install.